# Clang wants me to write ::std::declval rather than std::declval

Tags: c++, clang

I am trying to compile my repo with clang in mac for first time. Clang gives errors for all usages of std namespaces. It always says that use ::std::whatever rather than std::whatever. Am I doing wrong about ADL or something else ?

If anyone wants to look at full source it is located at [repo](https://github.com/OzanCansel/speech/blob/master/src/speech/util.h)

It compiles when I write it as a ::std::whatever but i want to know why it enforces me to add global scope resolution operator ?

```
template <typename S, typename T>
class implements_left_stream
{
     template <typename SS, typename TT>
     static auto test ( int )
     -> decltype ( std::declval<SS &>() << std::declval<TT>(), std::true_type() );

     template <typename, typename>
     static auto test ( ... ) -> std::false_type;

public:
     static const bool value = decltype ( test<S, T> ( 0 ) ) ::value;
};
```

Error is:

```
speech/util.h:34:20: error: no template named 'declval' in namespace 'speech::impl::std'; did you mean '::std::declval'?
[build]      -> decltype ( std::declval<SS &>() << std::declval<TT>(), std::true_type() );
[build]                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]                    ::std::declval
[build] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:1147:1: note: '::std::declval' declared here
[build] declval() _NOEXCEPT;
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] to show us (in the question body itself), and it must include the header files you `#include`.

Comment: As a possible hint about your problem, think about where you do `#include <cxxabi.h>`...

Comment: Lastly, always explicitly include the files where functions and structures are declared or defined. In the case of [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) it's `<utility>`. While including that (outside of any namespaces) you will probably solve your problem as well.

Comment: Why are you including a header file while already in a namespace? Why do you not do [this](https://github.com/OzanCansel/speech/blob/master/src/speech/util.h#L20) at global scope?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to use [qualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup). The compiler looks in current namespace and traverses upwards until it finds the needed namespace std. If it finds it it will search only in that namespace for the called function. E.g.

```
namespace a {
namespace std { // <--
    std::cout << ... // will only search in current namespace a::std
}
}

namespace a {
namespace std { // <--
namespace b {
    std::cout << ... // will only search in parent namespace a::std
}
}
}

namespace a {
namespace b {
    std::cout << ... // will only search in namespace ::std
}
}

// Error, can't find a::std::func
namespace a {
namespace std {
    void func() {};
namespace std { // <--
    std::func() // will only search in current namespace a::std::std, not in a::std
}
}
}

// Error, can't find std::declval
#include <utility>
namespace speech {
namespace impl {
namespace std { } // <-- Namespace created by include cxxabi.h
    decltype ( std::declval<SS &>() << std::declval<TT>(), std::true_type() ); // will only search in parent namespace speech::impl::std
}
}
```

Your namespace `speech::impl::std` shadows the namespace `std`.

The compiler won't traverse upwards after it finds one namespace with the same name even if this produces an error.

EDIT:

After I looked into your code I saw that you created the namespace `speech::impl`. Inside of this namespace you included the header cxxabi.h and you compiled with apple-clang. This created the namespace `speech::impl::std` that shadows the namespace `std`.

cxxabi.h for apple-clang contains the lines

```
namespace std {
    class type_info; // forward declaration
}
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that this problem stems from `#include <someStdHeader>` while inside some namespace and not at global scope.

Comment: @MaxLanghof This has nothing to do with the include. Look at my fourth example

Comment: But the code doesn't define `speech::impl::std`, not by itself anyway. And the `std::declval` function is not called from inside a `std` namespace.

Comment: It has to do with the include because that's how `namespace std` gets inside `namespace impl`. I'm not saying you're wrong, just that the root of the issue is the `#include` not being at global scope.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Now I think I understand it after I looked into the code.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Ah EDIT part enlightened me :) Good job it is solved.

Answer (score 3):

From error message, you have `namespace speech::impl::std` and are in namespace `namespace speech::impl` (or have corresponding `using`).

so namespace `std` refers to `speech::impl::std` instead of expected `::std`.